# Clearing text on UITextView while begin edit

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextview

On a UIViewController I have placed an editable UITextView with some text to be displayed while loading say "Some comment". My requirement is that when I click inside the text view, the pre-defined text should get cleared i.e. the text view should be blank and should no more show "Some Comment" text on it.

I used textViewDidBeginEditing as follows, but is not hitting the method itself:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.text = @"";
}
```

Do I need to raise any events for this or I need to define anything else for making the program to hit that method when the user clicks inside the text view.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the delegate for the UITextView inside the .Xib File by connecting it to the File's Owner.

```
     myTextView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I don't have a xib file for it... I have defined it inside the code... How do I set delegate inside the code?